# Why might a sitecore presentation component produce different output dependent on domain?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

As I can't post code I'm asking this as a theoretical question, but giving a scenario.

I have a "newsroom" sublayout, which staticaly binds a couple of XSLTs to list latest news and latest events. The sublayout is used on a newsroom item, the events and news items are descendants of it (though not direct child items, there are a couple of layers of folders to categorise and date items).

The subayout is in use in around 10 sites in our solution with no problem. Each site is a clone of our main site with an extra language version added. We hae succesfully used this with (amongst others) Japanese, Chinese, Russian, Polish and Czech language sites.

Our most recent clone (Turkish), however, shows no items in the event or news lists. The items exist and are published, and display as expected when browsed individually.

The presentation details for the newsroom item are identical to all other newsroom items.

Even more perplexing, the newsoom item itself, when displayed in the context of a different domain, displays correctly.

i.e.

```
www.mysite.com/sitecore/content/my_turkish_site/path/newsroom?sc_lang=tr-TR
```

shows the lists without a problem, including dates formatted according to culture, but

```
www.mysite.com.tr/sitecore/content/my_turkish_site/path/newsroom?sc_lang=tr-TR
```

shows empty lists.

The exact same problem occurs if language is switched to English (the language of the source of the clone)

Almost all of the Turkish site is working properly.

None of the presentation components are marked as cachable.

None of the presentation components have a specified data source (i.e. they all use the current item/descendants axis)

What are the **possible** causes of this problem, and how can I test them?

EDIT:
For Mark Ursino
This is the site definition (slightly fictionalised). I can't post that much more of the web.config...

```
<site name="www.mysite.com.tr" patch:after="site[@name='www.mysite.com.au']" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/CloneData/TurkishClone" hostName="www.mysite.com.tr" startItem="/Turkey_Home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" language="tr-TR" />
```

Some debugging shows that the XSLTs aren't matching the template when the item is viewed in the Turkish context.
This is the debug match used (the select is what we use in our for-each):

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(./descendant::item[@template='newsitem' and @id!=$topNewsId and sc:fld('__created',.)])"/>
```

It matches on the same item viewed from other domains.

Debug output shows the Turkish site thinks the template is `newsıtem` instead of `newsitem` (the i is wrong!).

I've also tested viewing the newsroom of other sites through the Turkish domain - the problem is the same.
We have the same problem with items based on the eventitem template, and apparently with an Image Spot template.

Comment: Can you provide your <sites> configuration?

Comment: @MarkUrsino - see update. It's an interestig one, as it seems the data is all correct, but that the site context can't handle it. The error persists between language versions, the data is correctly displayed by the same components in a diferent site context. Data from other sites doesn't display in the Turkish site context. All the sites in the <sites> are built in the same way, only name, path, hostname and language differ.

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting. Perhaps this would be good to submit to Sitecore support (http://support.sitecore.net). Provide them with your `web.config`, logs, and a screenshot of your tree structure. If you run `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` does it render the config as you expect it per your patch files or is something off in the `<sites>` section?

Comment: The sites section looks fine, all present and correct, in the order expected, all attributes as defined in the SiteDefinition.config. It's looking like a possible support case, but I thought I'd throw it out here for curiosities sake :-) I can't for the life of me work out how site context could be responsible for misreading a template key, when the key is intact and correct in the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Sitecore template names are converted to lower case for use in XSLT comparison, by the Sitecore XSLT extensions.

This lower case conversion hasn't been set as culturally invariant. In Turkish, forcing lower casing of a upper case `I` gives the lower case `ı`

Sitecore has replaced calls with `ToLower()` in the Sitecore API with `ToLowerInvariant()` as of 6.5 rev.110419

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

As we're not upgrading to 6.5 quite yet we'll be using template IDs rather than names in XSLT for now.

.Net info on strings and culture, including specifically the "Turkish I problem"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the language, culture and context item id, lang, version within your events lister and xslts?

If that shows anything unexpected you could step-in to some of the Sitecore pipeline resolvers with Reflector Pro's external assembly debugging.

Comment: I had a fair amount of that printed out, though not culture, which would have highlighted the problem, I think. I've answered my own question above - it's in the Sitecore XSLT extensions that lower casing without ensuring cultural invariance caused the problem.